# Difference of Two Continuous Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution, density-function

Suppose we have two independent uniformly distributed random variables on intervals $X$ on $[a, b]$ and $Y$ on $[c, d]$. What is the pdf of $Z=X-Y$ in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

As $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
$$f_{xy}(x,y)=\frac{1}{ b-a}\times \frac{1}{ d-c}$$
Let $ Z=X-Y $
$$F_{z}(z)=F_{z}(Z<z)=F_{z}(X-Y<z)$$
$$ =\int_{?}^{?} \int_{a?}^{y+z?} f_{xy}(x,y)dxdy$$
How set the bounds of this integral properly? If you can explain. I'd be very glad.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You cannot find that . Do you have independence of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: @geetha290krm yes

Comment: Hint: Can you find $F_Z(z) = \mathbb{P}[Z \le z]$?

Comment: I am having problems with the integral bounds

Comment: can you please update your question with what you have so far

Comment: It should be $$
\mathbb P(X-Y<z)=\int_a^b\int_{\max(c,x-z)}^{d}dy\,dx.
$$

Comment: How to work on the term $max(c,x-z)$

Comment: Assuming that you have thoroughly checked the formula above. The standard trick to work on it is as follows: Since $\max(c,x-z)=c$ if $c>x-z$ and $\max(c,x-z)=x-z$ if $c\le x-z$ we get
$$
\int_a^{c+z}\int_c^d\,dy\,dx+\int_{c+z}^b\int_{x-z}^ddy\,dx.
$$